# How do I add a variable into a specific registry key path via Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I currently have a script which looks for a specific program to exist in Add/Remove programs and I would like to add the "Dell Command" into registry to confirm.

```
#Find the Dell Command Update in Add/Remove Programs
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | 
% {Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath} | 
where {$_.Displayname -match "Dell Command"} |
sort Displayname | select DisplayName
```

Comment: what do you mean by "*add dell command*"? What should be the expected result?

Comment: In add or remove programs, I am looking for a program called Dell Command to exist. Since it does, I would like the DisplayName to be turned into a variable and set under "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\" path

Comment: This helps tons! I was able to add the variable into a path I wanted to however it added it as a REG_DWORD type, I would like it as a string.

Comment: I tried Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\' -PropertyType String -Name $variable and got an error

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to create a key based on the value returned from your search, you can do the following:

```
$dellCommand = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Where-Object -Property "DisplayName" -Match "Dell Command").DisplayName
$regKeyPath  = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\$dellCommand"
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $regKeyPath)) {
        Write-Output -InputObject "$regKeyPath doesn't exist. Creating key."
        $newKey = New-Item -Path $regKeyPath -Force  #Create the key if it doesn't exist.

        #Add Property values to the key
        #$newKey | New-ItemProperty -Name "blah" -Value "valuevalue" -PropertyType "type" -Force 
    }
    else {
        Write-Output -InputObject "Key already exists: [$dellCommand]."
    }
```

Here, you can test to see if the key already exists and create it if it doesn't. Since `New-Item` produces an output of the object, you can use that to pipe into `New-ItemProperty` if needed to add properties to the key (*demonstrated above*).